# How to configure different font sizes for named urxvt windows?

Tags: terminal, fonts, rxvt, x-resources

I have two `urxvt` terminal windows, and I want each of them to be configured in slightly different way. I've set a different name for the windows via the `-name` flag. I added the following to the `.Xresources` and that set the "default" font configuration for all the terminal windows:

```
URxvt*font:           xft:monospace:size=8
URxvt*boldFont:       xft:monospace:bold:size=8
URxvt*italicFont:     xft:monospace:italic:size=8
URxvt*boldItalicFont: xft:monospace:bold:italic:size=8
```

How to configure the terminals individually using the `.Xresources` file?

Answer (score 0):

You may use command line switches for setup fonts and another parameters for new windows. I am use client-server model (urxvtd / urxvtc). Examples:
Start new terminal window with custom fonts: `

```
urxvtc --font "xft:IBM 3270:size=8"
```

Turn on transparency/coloring:

```
urxvtc -depth 32 -bg rgba:3000/2300/5100/d000
```

and much much more other parameters. Also, you may change font sizes on the fly, via hotkeys. Read the [ArchWiki articles](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rxvt-unicode) about this.

Comment: Is there a way to convert this to a Xresources config?